# SQL Server : get a substring (first name, last name, surname)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a way to get table below:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp]
(
    [ID_TASK] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_NAME] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_PHONE] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#temp] 
VALUES ('ID005', 'Anderson Abreu Oliveira', '68157120'),
       ('ID006', 'Gonzalez-IV', '64106929'),
       ('ID009', 'Parker W.H.', '60994308')
```

I'm using this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    ID_TASK, CHNAME_NAME,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CHNAME_NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME)))) AS SURNAME,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CHNAME_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) + 1, LEN(CHNAME_NAME) - (CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) - 1)))) AS  FIRSTNAME,
    REPLACE((RTRIM(LTRIM(CHNAME_PHONE))), '8-', '') AS CHNAME_PHONE
FROM 
    [dbo].[#temp]
```

but I get this result:

[image]

How do I fix this SQL query to get the desired result? Thank you

Comment: There are tons of edge cases your sample data do not cover.  In general, it is very hard to detect first, middle, and last names.

Comment: Try `PATINDEX('%[ -]%', CHNAME_NAME);` to catch both spaces and dashes but as @TimBiegeleisen said there are plenty of edge cases.

Comment: No process is ever perfect, but do you realize that by storing all parts of the name inside a single field, that the field does not store atomic data- and so now the entire table violates First Normal Form?  For example, if someone marries and changes their last name- how would you update that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp]
(
    [ID_TASK] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_NAME] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_PHONE] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#temp] 
VALUES ('ID005', 'Anderson Abreu Oliveira', '68157120'),
       ('ID006', 'Gonzalez-IV', '64106929'),
       ('ID009', 'Parker W.H.', '60994308');

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [ID_TASK],
           LEFT([CHNAME_NAME], IIF( CHARINDEX(' ', [CHNAME_NAME]) = 0 , CHARINDEX('-', [CHNAME_NAME])-1, CHARINDEX(' ', [CHNAME_NAME]))) AS T,
           [CHNAME_NAME],
           [CHNAME_PHONE]
    FROM #Temp
)
SELECT [ID_TASK],
       [CHNAME_NAME],
       T AS SURNAME,
       LTRIM(REPLACE(CASE WHEN (T IS NULL) OR (T = '') THEN [CHNAME_NAME] ELSE SUBSTRING([CHNAME_NAME], LEN(T)+1, LEN([CHNAME_NAME])) END, '-', '')) FirstName,
       [CHNAME_PHONE]
FROM CTE;
```

Results:

```
+---+---------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
|   | ID_TASK |       CHNAME_NAME       |  SURNAME  |    FirstName    | CHNAME_PHONE |
+---+---------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1 | ID005   | Anderson Abreu Oliveira | Anderson  | Abreu Oliveira |     68157120 |
| 2 | ID006   | Gonzalez-IV             | Gonzalez  | IV              |     64106929 |
| 3 | ID009   | Parker W.H.             | Parker    | W.H.           |     60994308 |
+---+---------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/OXQAV52991)**

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use `case..when` structure

with `CHARINDEX('-', CHNAME_NAME)` and `CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME)`

as in the [`following statement`](http://rextester.com/FFR46113) :

```
SELECT
    ID_TASK, CHNAME_NAME,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CHNAME_NAME, 1, 
         (Case CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) When 0 Then CHARINDEX('-', CHNAME_NAME)-1 
               Else CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) End)))) AS SURNAME, 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CHNAME_NAME, 
         (Case CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) When 0 Then CHARINDEX('-', CHNAME_NAME) 
               Else CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) End) + 1, 
                    LEN(CHNAME_NAME) - (CHARINDEX(' ', CHNAME_NAME) - 1)))) AS  FIRSTNAME,
    REPLACE((RTRIM(LTRIM(CHNAME_PHONE))), '8-', '') AS CHNAME_PHONE
FROM 
    [dbo].[#temp]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an advanced thing to achieve I've done some SQL to get you there, but not tidied it up...

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    [ID_TASK] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_NAME] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CHNAME_PHONE] [nvarchar](300) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 'ID005','Anderson Abreu Oliveira','68157120' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID006','Gonzalez-IV','64106929' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID009','Parker W.H.','60994308'


select ID_TASK, col1, col2, col3
from
(
  select a.ID_TASK, Item , 'col' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), ItemNumber) ItemNumber
  from @temp a
  CROSS APPLY [dbo].[DelimitedSplit] ( REPLACE(a.CHNAME_NAME, '-', ' '), ' '  ) b
) d
pivot
(
  MAX(item)
  for itemNumber in (col1, col2, col3)
) piv
GROUP BY ID_TASK, col1, col2, col3
```

**Helper function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit] (
    @pString VARCHAR(MAX),
    @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
    WITH E1(N) AS ( -- 10
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
    E3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b, E2 c),
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E3 a, E3 b, E3 c, E3 d),
    cteTally(N) AS (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP ( DATALENGTH( ISNULL( @pString, 1 ) ) ) ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) FROM E4
    ),
    cteStart(N1) AS (
        SELECT t.N + 1
        FROM cteTally t
        WHERE ( SUBSTRING( @pString, t.N, 1 ) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0 )
    )
-- ------
    SELECT
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY s.N1 ),
        Item = SUBSTRING( @pString, s.N1, ISNULL( NULLIF( CHARINDEX( @pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1 ), 0) - s.N1, 1000000 ) )
    FROM cteStart s
GO
```